# ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte when using program on internet

Tags: java, sockets, client, server, objectinputstream

I created an application with TCP, it works nice when I used it on a local network with `127.0.0.1` but the server refused to works when a client try to connect to him from an another network.

I don't know what this error means and how to resolve it and I can't anderstand that an application could works only on LAN.

```
public class Reception {

InputStream inObjet = null;
BufferedReader inString = null;
ObjectInputStream recVec2i = null;

public Reception(Socket socket) {
    try {
        this.inObjet = socket.getInputStream();
        this.inString = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        this.recVec2i = new ObjectInputStream(inObjet);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public Vecteur2i recevoir() {
    Vecteur2i to = new Vecteur2i();
    try {

        to = (Vecteur2i) recVec2i.readObject();

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        to = new Vecteur2i(1000, 1000);
    }
    return to;
}

public String recevoirString() {
    String chaine = "";
    try {
        chaine = inString.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return chaine;
}

public void fermerReception() {
    try {
        inString.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        inObjet.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Emission.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        recVec2i.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reception.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

And here the exception :

> avr. 22, 2015 9:33:33 PM Snake.Reception recevoir Grave: null
>   java.io.EOFException  at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2597)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1316)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
>     at Snake.Reception.recevoir(Reception.java:41)  at
>   Snake.Partie.cycleDeJeu(Partie.java:55)

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix different types of stream via the same socket when one or more of them is buffered, and both `BufferedInputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` are buffered. The buffers will 'steal' data from each other. In your case you should do all the I/O via the object stream. It has String-based methods.